# Double relation to the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a double relation on the same table but i cannot access the data from other tables.

I have a devise table for users, and other one that will have "their posts".

Reclamacoes table

```
("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
"usuario_reclamante_id" integer, 
"usuario_reclamado_id" integer, 
"titulo" varchar, 
"conteudo" text, 
"created_at" datetime NOT NULL, 
"updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)
```

And than, the model reclamacao

```
class Reclamacao < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "usuario_reclamante_id"
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "usuario_reclamado_id"
end
```

The User model

```
has_many :reclamacao
```

In the view, when i'm trying to access the user email, doing something like this:

```
<% @allReclamacoes.each do |reclamacao| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= reclamacao.titulo %></td>
        <td><%= reclamacao.conteudo %></td>
        <td><%= reclamacao.usuario_reclamante_id.email %></td>
        <td><%= reclamacao.usuario_reclamado_id %></td>
    </tr>        
<% end %>
```

The creating of the element:

```
 def create
        @reclamacao = Reclamacao.new reclamacao_params
        @reclamacao.usuario_reclamante_id = current_user
        if @reclamacao.save
            flash[:success] = "criado com sucesso"
        else
            flash[:error] = "falha ao criar"
        end

        redirect_to paginainicial_path
    end
```

and than

> undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

Whats the problem in the relation that i'm making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you're naming both of the `belongs_to` associations the same, which will certainly cause problems.  You need to explicitly name one or both of them, like this:

```
class Reclamacao < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :reclamente, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "usuario_reclamante_id"
    belongs_to :reclamado, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "usuario_reclamado_id"
end
```

You can simplify even further by matching the named associations with the foreign key names.  Then you can skip the foreign key parts:

```
class Reclamacao < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :usuario_reclamente, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :usuario_reclamado, class_name: "User"
end
```

Similarly, you would need to set up 2 separate `has_many` associations on the User side.

Also, this line is wrong:
`@reclamacao.usuario_reclamante_id = current_user`

You need to either set the id to the current_user's id:
`@reclamacao.usuario_reclamante_id = current_user.id`

..or, even better, use the named association:
`@reclamacao.usuario_reclamante = current_user`

Finally, to access the email in the view, you need to use the named association:

`<td><%= reclamacao.usuario_reclamante.email %></td>`

Comment: I'm new to rails, i have some doubts. In the has_many association, i should declare the foreign key either? Because the table user doesnt have a foreign key column. Second, to access the data on the view, i should use the varIwant.reclamante.email ?

Comment: I just updated my answer to answer these 2 questions.

Comment: talking about the relation in the user model, it should be done like this?     `has_many :reclamante, class_name: "Reclamacao"
    has_many :reclamado, class_name: "Reclamacao" `

Comment: If you name them that way, you'll also need to declare the foreign key names.  Otherwise, Rails won't know which one is which.